# Signature of the declaration of a function in Ocaml

Tags: function, ocaml

I have defined a function like the following:

```
let ff (f1: a_function) (f2: a_function) (v0: type1) (v1: type2): type3 = ...
```

And another function like the following works:

```
let f: type1 -> type2 -> type3 = ff f1 f2
```

But another declaration like the following does not work:

```
let f (v0: type1) (v1: type2): type3 = ff f1 f2
```

The error message is:

```
Error: This expression has type
         type1 -> type2 -> type3
       but an expression was expected of type type3
```

I have always thought that `let f: type1 -> type2 -> type3` is same as `let f (v0: type1) (v1: type2): type3`. Could anyone tell me why the first declaration works but not the second?

Thank you very much

**PS1:** My key question is, given `let f (v0: type1) (v1: type2): type3 = ff f1 f2`, isn't the type of `f` `type1 -> type2 -> type3`?

If `let f (v0: type1) (v1: type2): type3 = ff f1 f2` and `let f (v0: type1) (v1: type2): type3 = ff f1 f2` returns same type of `f`, what is the difference between these 2 signatures?

Comment: Please, could you include the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Joshua Smith: I have added the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments `v0`, `v1` of your second definition are dangling. This declaration works, on the other hand:

```
module type TimurTest =
  sig
    type type1
    type type2
    type type3
    type functional1
    type functional2
    val f1 : functional1
    val f2 : functional2
    val ff : functional1 -> functional2 -> type1 -> type2 ->type3
  end

module MyTest(M:TimurTest) =
  struct
    let f : M.type1 -> M.type2 -> M.type3 = M.ff M.f1 M.f2
    let f (v0: M.type1) (v1: M.type2) : M.type3 = M.ff M.f1 M.f2 v0 v1
    let g (v0: M.type1) (v1: M.type2) = M.ff M.f1 M.f2
  end
```

The last line answers your PS (notice I haven't specified the return type of `g`, to let the compiler infer what it should be): since its definition ignores arguments `v0` and `v1`, the [curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) meaning of `g (v0:type1) (v1:type2) = ff f1 f2` gives it the type `type1 -> type2 -> type1 -> type2 -> type3`. Basically, you require two additional arguments whose value you're going to throw away (not passing them to `ff f1 f2`, which is going to require two of its own).

And indeed, when declaring the above module, part of the response of the compiler is:

```
      val g : M.type1 -> M.type2 -> M.type1 -> M.type2 -> M.type3
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you please take a look at my PS?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in your definition of `f` you say it takes two arguments of types `type1` and `type2` and returns a result of type `type3`. So the body should have `type3`. Instead it has type `type1 -> type2 -> type3` as you can see from your definition of `f` and that's what the compiler tells you.

Perhaps what you meant is:

```
let f (v0: type1) (v1: type2): type3 = ff f1 f2 v0 v1
```

Considering your PS the type of `f` is not what you say because `f` doesn't type-check. I tried to answer why above. If you omitted return type of `f` like this:

```
let f' (v0: type1) (v1: type2) = ff f1 f2
```

then the type of `f'` would be `type1 -> type2 -> type1 -> type2 -> type3`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you please take a look at my PS?

Comment: answer modified to answer your PS.